# jquery validation to work only on a single button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have multiple submit button on a page and i want to validate form only on a particular button click not on any other submit button's click. i am not getting a good a solution for this. My validation code is here

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var a = $("form").validate({  invalidHandler: function (d, b) {
                    var e = b.numberOfInvalids(); if (e) {
                        var c = e == 1 ? "You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted." : "You missed " + e + " fields. They have been highlighted."; $(".box .content").removeAlertBoxes();
                        $(".box .content").alertBox(c, { type: "warning", icon: true, noMargin: false });
                        $(".box .content .alert").css({ width: "", margin: "0", borderLeft: "none", borderRight: "none", borderRadius: 0 })
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".box .content").removeAlertBoxes()
                    }
                }, showErrors: function (c, d) {
                    this.defaultShowErrors(); var b = this; $.each(d, function () {
                        var f = $(this.element); var e = f.parent().find("label.error").hide(); e.addClass("red"); e.css("width", ""); f.trigger("labeled"); e.fadeIn()
                    })
                }
                })
        });


        </script>
```

can i specify class or id for jquery validation instead of causing it to occur on every submit button's click

Answer (score 1):

i just got my answer at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference

Skipping validation on submit
To skip validation while still using a submit-button, add a class="cancel" to that input.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" class="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do one thing. On which button you want this form validation. add a javascript function at `onclick()` event of that. And then put your form validation java-script given above within that java-script function. I hope it will be work. And remove `$(document).ready(function ()` from that javascript code.

thanks